# How to extract period and variable name from dataframe column strings for multiindex panel data preparation

Tags: python, pandas, panel, multi-index

I'm new to Python and could not find the answer I'm looking for anywhere.

I have a DataFrame that has the following structure:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=list('abc'), data={'A1': range(3), 'A2': range(3),'B1': range(3), 'B2': range(3), 'C1': range(3), 'C2': range(3)})
df
Out[1]:
   A1 A2 B1 B2 C1 C2
a  0  0  0  0  0  0
b  1  1  1  1  1  1
c  2  2  2  2  2  2
```

Where the numbers are periods and he letters are variables. I'd like to transform the columns in a way, that I split the periods and variables into a multiindex. The desired output would look like that

```
   A     B     C   
   1  2  1  2  1  2
a  0  0  0  0  0  0
b  1  1  1  1  1  1
c  2  2  2  2  2  2
```

I've tried the following:

```
periods = list(range(1, 3))
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('\d+', '')
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.columns, periods])
```

That seams to be multiplying the columns and raising an ValueError: Length mismatch

in my dataframe I have 72 periods and 12 variables.

Thanks in advance for your help!

**Edit**:  I realized that I haven't been precise enough. I have several columns names something like Impressions1, Impressions2...Impressions72 and hhi1, hhi2...hhi72. So df.columns.str[0],df.columns.str[1] does not work for me, as all column names have a different length. I think the solution might contain regex but I can't figure out how to do it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what actually solved my issue:

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df.columns.str.extract(r'([a-zA-Z]+)([0-9]+)'), names=[None, None])
```

Thanks @Scott Boston for your inspiration to the solution!

Answer (score 3):

Use [`pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples.html):

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(zip(df.columns.str[0],df.columns.str[1])))
print(df)
   A     B     C   
   1  2  1  2  1  2
a  0  0  0  0  0  0
b  1  1  1  1  1  1
c  2  2  2  2  2  2
```

**Alternative:**

```
pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([tuple(name) for name in df.columns])
```

or

```
pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(map(tuple, df.columns))
```

Comment: that makes more sense actually

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!!! That almost did it. I realized that I haven't been precise enough. I have several columns names something like Impressions1, Impressions2...Impressions72 and hhi1, hhi2...hhi72. So the df.columns.str[0],df.columns.str[1] part does not work for me, as all column names have a different length. I think the solution might contain regex but I can't figure out how to do it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use, `.str.extract` and `from_frame`:

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df.columns.str.extract('(.)(.)'), names=[None, None])
```

Output:

```
   A     B     C   
   1  2  1  2  1  2
a  0  0  0  0  0  0
b  1  1  1  1  1  1
c  2  2  2  2  2  2
```